# Change 2 values with Jquery text replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change two prices on the page rather than one. so change if £65 or £35.

How do I add a either/or to this function?

```
$('#shipping-method > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.price > label')

 .filter(function () { 

return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "£65.00"; 

}).text('Quote Price');
```

Comment: Use [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: `return this.innerHTML.match(/£(65|35).00/);` is a solution.

Comment: I want to have something like        == "£65.00 or £35.00";

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```
$("#shipping-method > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.price > label")
.filter(function () { 
  return /£65\.00|£35\.00/.test(this.innerHTML); 
}).text("Quote Price");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple or `||` operator

```
$('#shipping-method > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.price > label')

 .filter(function () { 

return ($.trim(this.innerHTML) == "£65.00" || $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "£35.00"); 

}).text('Quote Price');
```